# Regular expression: Identify all html tag except <tr>, <td>, </td> or </tr>

Tags: java, regex, html-parsing

I would like to ask **how can I remove all html tags except** `<tr>, <td>, </td>, or </tr>`

I can
- Identify all html tag using `<.*?>`
- Identify `<tr>, <td>, </td>, </tr>` using `^((?!<tr>)(?!<td>)(?!</td>)(?!</tr>).)*$`.

But I just do not know how to combine both criteria into one.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Use a Parser is how you can do this.

Comment: It's always good, if you specify the language, that you're using and welcome :)

Comment: Ok, I understand. For this I am using Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below regex would match all the tags but not of td or tr.

```
<(?!\/?(?:t[dr])>).*?>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rR5zI0/2)

Comment: Any idea which is the suitable tools?
By the way your answer just keep </td> and </tr>, It still omits <tr> and <td>

Comment: which lang are you running?

Comment: I am using Java, actually I try to display the content of email which is written in html in a primeface datatable.